# mysql return rows matching year month

Tags: sql, mysql

How would I go about doing a query that returns results of all rows that contain dates for current year and  month at the time of query.

Timestamps for each row are formated as such: yyyy-mm-dd

I know it probably has something to do with the date function and that I must somehow  set a special parameter to make it spit out like such: yyyy-mm-%%.

Setting days to be wild card character would do the trick but I can't seem to figure it out how to do it.

Here is a link to for quick reference to date-time functions in mysql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think EXTRACT is the function you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM timestamp_field) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW())
```

Comment: Ahh, you read my mind. This is exactly what I needed! Thanks Eric.

Answer (score 5):

you could extract the year and month using a function, but that will not be able to use an index.

if you want scalable performance, you need to do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE some_date_column BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-01-31'
```

Comment: +1 on this - the solution I gave solves the problem, but will likely NOT scale well if you have lots of data.

Comment: This answer is still helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from someTable where year(myDt) = 2009 and month(myDt) = 9 and day(myDt) = 12
```